# How can i decide which ifDescr index i will use in SNMP?

Tags: networking, snmp, bandwidth

I want to monitor bandwidth utilization for a number of devices. However in SNMP, the ethernet card's indexes are different for each computer. For example in localhost these are the values:

> Sent GET request to localhost : 161
>
> ifDescr.1 Software Loopback Interface 1   ifDescr.2 WAN Miniport
>   (SSTP)
>
> ifDescr.3 WAN Miniport (L2TP)   ifDescr.4 WAN Miniport (PPTP)
>
> ifDescr.5 WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
>
> ifDescr.6 WAN Miniport (IPv6)
>
> ifDescr.7 WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
>
> ifDescr.8 WAN Miniport (IP)
>
> ifDescr.9 RAS Async Adapter
>
> ifDescr.10 WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
>
> ifDescr.11 Microsoft Teredo T?nel Ba§da?t?r?c?s?
>
> ifDescr.12
>
> ifDescr.13
>
> ifDescr.14
>
> ifDescr.15 Realtek PCIe GBE
>   Family Controller
>
> ifDescr.16 Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230
>
> ifDescr.17 Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #9
>
> ifDescr.18 Bluetooth Ayg?t? (Ki?isel Alan A§?)
>
> ifDescr.19 Bluetooth Ayg?t? (RFCOMM Protokol? TDI)
>
> ifDescr.20 Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #10
>
> ifDescr.21 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller-QoS Packet Scheduler-0
>   000
>
> ifDescr.22 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller-WFP LightWeight
>   Filter -0000
>
> ifDescr.23 WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
>
> ifDescr.24 WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
>
> ifDescr.25 WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000

Bandwidth incoming:

> Sent GET request to localhost : 161
>
> ifInOctets.1 0
>
> ifInOctets.2 0
>
> ifInOctets.3 0
>
> ifInOctets.4 0
>
> ifInOctets.5 0
>
> ifInOctets.6 0
>
> ifInOctets.7 0
>
> ifInOctets.8 0
>
> ifInOctets.9 0
>
> ifInOctets.10 0
>
> ifInOctets.11 0
>
> ifInOctets.12 0
>
> ifInOctets.13 0
>
> ifInOctets.14 0
>
> ifInOctets.15 54112558
>
> ifInOctets.16 0
>
> ifInOctets.17 0
>
> ifInOctets.18 0
>
> ifInOctets.19 0
>
> ifInOctets.20 0
>
> ifInOctets.21 54112558
>
> ifInOctets.22 54112558
>
> ifInOctets.23 0
>
> ifInOctets.24 0
>
> ifInOctets.25 0

So, i need to look indexes 15,21 and 22. However in other computers indexes will differ and also card names will differ(mine is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller). How can i find out which index i should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding of interface name is done by the OS so pretty much depends on how the interfaces are brought up and then discovered/ enumerated by the SNMP agent. If a specific interface (identifier via ifDescr possibly) is what you are interested in then you do a lookup by pulling the ifDescr column and then getting the index. For example if the interest is in

"Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"

then that's ifIndex 15 and you should query IfInOctets.15 on a specific host. On another host it is possible that the Index will be something else. For example on my MAC I typically get "en0" as the interface (on my Linux server it can be something like "eth0") and get the ifDescr value as following with IfIndex of 5

IF-MIB::ifDescr.5 = STRING: en1

So you should plan on adjusting accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! But i need to know that is there a way to monitor bandwidth utilization of many computers without knowing their ethernet card names. I mean in order to do this, do we need to provide the names or first query with ifDescr then manually decide which index it is in?

Comment: No you don't need to know the name because depending upon the controller type and driver that comes along the ifDescr will be different. Given the need to monitor bandwidth utilization across multiple devices, I'd query for oper/admin status along with In/OutOctets and compute only for interfaces that are oper/admin up. The other thing that might be of further interest is that how these interfaces are related to one another (physical to logical) so that one can aggregate and report appropriately, but that's a next level detail you may want to consider incorporating.

Comment: Thank you very much! These information were really helpful for me. I have one last question. When i query ifInOctets i got 3 same number(54112558) in different indexes.(Values i gave above) Their descriptions are: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller-QoS Packet Scheduler-0 000 and Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller-WFP LightWeight Filter -0000. When i calculate incoming bandwidth will i sum them up or will i take only one of them?

Comment: That was the last point I was referring to in my previous comment (the next level detail) that some of the interfaces might be related to each other and that will require understanding of relationships between various interfaces which will go beyond the MIB walk of interfaces table. So a blind aggregation will provide incorrect data the best you can do is report all three however if you can figure out the relationship it will be a lot more helpful your end users :-)

Comment: Okay, i'll check the relationships. Thanks a lot for your interest and all these helpful answers! :)

Comment: Hi, would you mind if i ask you a new question? :) I am trying to show bandwidth utilization on a graph like in the task manager. However the formulas i found in the internet (Input Bandwidth=(∆ifInOctets * 8) /No. of seconds in ∆)(Utilization=(Bandwidth/ifSpeed) *100) gives me values in broad range (e.g. one is 0.002 the next one is 9.7). And it's too hard to show them in one graph and they also seem wrong. I do the queries in every 10 seconds(i tried 3 and 5 too). Is the problem in the formula or am i doing some other things wrong?

Comment: Computation of bits per second  (multiplying by 8) is fine if the need is report in Gbps/Mbps or against the speed of the interface further for percentage calculation. The utilization computation is calculating percentage which is good to display against a fixed y-scale, this is fine as long as 10% on 1Gbps and 50% of 100 Mbps are well understood in your charts. 9.7 looks reasonable incoming traffic from your example.  Consider including IfOutOctets as well to your equation (Rx+Tx) will give the BW. Check if the interface is in duplex mode as well which can change your comp a bit more.

Comment: My point is when i calculate utilization i have values 0.002 and then 9.7. When i want to show them on a xy-graph,if i set y axis from 0 to 0.1 then i can't handle the value 9.7 or if i set y axis from 0 to 10 then i can't handle showing 0.002(it seems like 0). Also, today i run the program again and i have a negative value for utilization. I think something is wrong, but i still can't figure out what is it?

Comment: There is not much you can do for the range you have at hand that is plotting 0.002 and something like 9.7 at the same time. Best is to filter out data that does not add to the overall impact something like top N where N can be adjusted based on choice/range etc. Negative value may happen in counter rollover/resets are not accouted for in delta computations.